# How to send two parameters to action using button in ActiveColumn Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am having a little bit of trouble with the ActionColumn in Yii2 basic application.

I want to send two parameters to an action called `activate`. The action takes one parameter without any issues. However, when I want to send him the second one, it starts to act up.

To get the second parameter I need to loop through an object to get it. However, every time I call the index page I get a `Undefined Variable: teamId` Error. Not sure what I am missing in the function. Am I doing the loop wrong or anything?

This is what I have in the ActionColumn in the `index.php`:

```
[
                'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
                'template' => '{activate}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'activate' => function($url, $model) {
                        $userId = $model->iduser;
                        foreach ($model->teamIdteams as $team) {
                            $teamId = $team->idteam;
                        }
                        // return Html::img($url);
                        return Html::a('Click Me', ['activate', 'id' => $userId, 'team' => $teamId]);
                    }
                ],
            ],
```

What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to deal with situation where user isn't assigned to any team. When that situation occurs your `$teamId` variable is not set. Try adding something like `$teamId = null;` before your foreach cycle.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Works perfectly. Say, mind if I ask another question?